# Error in subfolder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, profile

I put my website in a sub folder so I get this error : 
CS0433: The type 'ProfileCommon' exists in both 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\99e3db3c\8dd0c57\App_Code.iwss2ssz.dll' and 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\99e3db3c\8dd0c57\assembly\dl3\4aaf4a82\00a6b770_83e2ce01\App_Code.DLL'

I have putted a profile properties in my web.config as

```
<properties>
    <add name="Name" type="string" />
    <add name="id" type="string" />
    <add name="type" type="string" />
  </properties>
```

I have noticed when I delete above section from web.config the error solve. Is there a way to have profile properties and put site in a sub folder too?

Answer (score 0):

You might have the same class definition in multiple libraries, perhaps you kept on your server an old file  that you no longer use. This usually happens when you copy the published website on the server and you have other files left there from a previous version.

Check the /bin folder and remove old and unused files and only deploy the files that are generated when publishing the website. To make sure you have only the currently needed files, use the option named "Delete all existing files prior to publish" when you publish the website. Delete the content of /bin folder on your server and upload only the new files. Might work without any other interventions if your website builds locally with no errors.